# Saving a Users Data from Scratch

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have an app that I want a user to select a location from the first time they open up the app. After they select their location, I want the location to be saved and certain buttons to be made available for certain locations. Currently, I have tried saving the User's Location, which I can achieve only when in the app, however, whenever the app is closed out the old data does not load.
My two questions are:

-- How do I save a User's Location throughout the Whole App

-- Which way is recommended to call the different links based on the User's Location?

(UPDATE):
What I have tried right now is Using NSUSERDEFAULTS. Here's my Code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self userLocationSave];

}
        -(void)userLocationSave
    {
        campusLocation = self.lblUserLocation.text;
        self.lblUserLocation.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self saveData];
    }

    -(void)saveData
    {
        NSString *saveLocation = self.lblUserLocation.text;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:saveLocation forKey:@"campusChoice"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    -(void)loadData
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"campusChoice"];
        [self.lblUserLocation setText:loadString];
    }
```

I then load the data in the viewDidAppear Method.

To clarify, campus location is an NSString that comes from a view controller where the user selects the persons data.

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain exactly what isn't working as expected.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you should load your data, not save your data.

Comment: NScoding is very easy to use https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html

Comment: Where then would I save my data?

Comment: If you're not getting the correct NSUserDefaults, try using CoreData. It seems like it would be unnecessary as you are using UserDeafults which should be fine.

Comment: `viewWillDisappear:` would be one choice for saving the data unless this is the root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are not actually saving the users app if the data is not there during the next session.

There are two good ways to persist data in iOS:
CoreData
NSUserDefaults

Sounds like NSUserDefaults would work for you.  Look up tutorials for how to save data using NSUserDefaults.

> Which way is recommended to call the different links based on the User's Location?

Not sure what you are asking here, if you clarify, I can edit my answer.